# how to tell when a new page is being spanned in jinja?

Tags: python, html, flask, html-table, jinja2

im using jinja and flask to render a table in a html template that i want to send as a pdf. the table will span multiple pages and I want the table headers to be visible on each page.

*How can I tell when the table is on a new page so that I can render a table header at the top of each new page that the table spans?*

thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you do but if you want to convert one web page in many pages in PDF then it would have to render many smaller tables on web page.

Comment: i dont think you understand what im asking, im using jinja to dynamically render a pdf. In the pdf I generate a table, depending on the data the table may span multiple pages. I want to add a table header row for each part of the table that is on a different page

Comment: you didn't show code so we can't understand how you do it. But I think still is the same solution - split table into many smaller tables with own header.

Comment: the data is dynamic so i cant just split the tables into smaller tables. the table could span 1 page or 10 pages. Showing my code wont be useful as the explanation of what i want to achieve is pretty simple

Comment: it doesn't matter you have dynamic data - you always can do `rows[0:5]`, `row[5:10]`,... `row[n:n+5]` to have 5 rows in separated tables. You can do it even in some loop. You didn't show code so I have no idea how you create this PDF and you can't expect better help.

Comment: actually it does matter because the data inside each row is also dynamic so they can be difference sizes so I cant do what you suggested. Again showing you the code won't help you lol because the issue is based on the fact that the data is dynamic

Comment: if you have dynamic data then you have to use different number of rows based on data size. But without code I can't say how to do it. So I can't help you. Maybe someone else can help you but I expect nobody will try it without your code. So, good luck.